# drupal 7 theming + gulp + sass + browserSync no css injection

Tags: drupal-7, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, browser-sync

I'm able to get browserSync.reload({stream:true}) to css inject into a wordpress theme.  When I try the same gulpfile.js in a Drupal 7 theme a hard reset works, browserSync.reload(), but css injection does nothing, browserSync.reload({stream:true}).

Any ideas?  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  Thank you in advance!

I did experience a segmentation fault issue when I moved this workflow into drupal 7, but was able to solve it with this post.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126880/how-do-i-prevent-drupal-raising-a-segmentation-fault-when-using-a-node-js-themin

Answer (score 0):

You have to use link_css module https://www.drupal.org/project/link_css because browser-sync currently doesn't handle css @imports